# Trigram For Heaven entity not working for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, entity

I was looking everywhere, but couldn't find answer. Sorry if there already is an answer. Anyway I have a navigation

```
   <div id="menu">
     <ul class="nav">
        <a href="#" id="pull">&#x2630;</a>
        <li><a href="index.php?site=home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?site=about">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?site=works">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?site=contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
```

And the Trigram For Heaven entity is not working for WP8. I was wondering if I did something wrong or do I really have to use a .png? It is working on my friends iPhone and in browser (tested).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the font most likely, have you tried changing it? To Arial Unicode MS perhaps?

Comment: @ToniPetrina I am using custom font. Should I try changing the font?

Comment: Well, not every font supports all Unicode characters AFAIK.

Comment: font was the answer mate.

Comment: Great, now just confirm my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode characters belong to certain fonts, like Arial Unicode MS and not all fonts support a wide range of Unicode characters.

To ensure that special Unicode characters are shown, you must change the font for the platform.