# Checkbox not visable on Mobiles

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, checkbox

I am working on a website for a Uni assignment and I have a strange mobile problem. I have created a checkbox that makes the menu hidden or visible on mobile with the checked function. It works just fine on my computer when I simulate a mobile browser in Chrome or Firefox or by using Resizer.

Although when I view it on a mobile (Android) the checkbox is not visible. I found the same on my tablet although there if I click the right part of the screen the menu appears. Both mobile and tablet are running Chrome for Mobiles though I have also tested it in Opera Mini and have the same problem. It runs fine on PC but isn't visible on Mobiles.

Here is my website: http://wonx.dk/pwdh/

And here is the relevant HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<label for="menuon">&#x2630; &#x25be;</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="menuon">
```

CSS:

```
label {
    font-size:36px;
}

label:hover {
    color:#F03B4E;
}


input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

/* Checkbox Default State (if deleted menu is always visable) */
nav {
   display:none;
}

/* When clicked/Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: check the styles in style.css line 106 input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
} you are moving the button from its position

Comment: what are the type of mobiles / tablets you're testing on (ios/android)? i can display the menus fine in my iPhone 4S on iOS8 using Chrome and Safari...

Comment: yeah, looks like this is an issue on Android only, just checked...

Comment: I have tested it on two android systems yes. Glad to hear it works fine on iOS.

Comment: Update: the { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; } keeps the actual checkbox off the screen. If i delete it then the checkbox appears at the top of the page. It should only be the label that is visible.

Comment: you may want to try one of the suggestions in my answer, if you like any, you may vote it up and/or accept it as the best one (big gray check mark), cheers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `&#x2630;` and `&#x25be;` - they are not working on Androids.

For testing purposes, try replacing them with actual words:

```
<label for="menuon">stripes arrow</label>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sc0rv3na/10/

Try using images, or a special fonts instead, eg [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/).

Here is a Font Awesome implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/sc0rv3na/14/

**EDIT**: Although that question is about Windows Phones, it basically answers this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21997373/2037924

> Unicode characters belong to certain fonts, like Arial Unicode MS and not all fonts support a wide range of Unicode characters.
>
> To ensure that special Unicode characters are shown, you must change the font for the platform.

**EDIT #2**: Here are a couple of ways to add a mobile menu icon to your site: http://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/